# Using OpenAPI/Swagger CodeGen without a swagger.json

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have a REST API that was not built with [Swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) in mind.  It has no swagger.json file.  I do not control this API.  The API is URL based, responses to GET, POST, and PUT requests, and returns JSON or XML.

Is there a path forward that would let me use the `swagger-codegen` tool with this API?  That is, I know I can normally generate client code for an API with

```
$ swagger-codegen generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l ruby -o /tmp/test/
```

What I want to know is if there's a way to

1. Write my own swagger.json file for the API
2. Do -- *something*? -- to transform the requests and responses into the format expected by this legacy REST API

Do the swagger/OpenAPI tools have anything that allows for the above, or is that outside the project's remit?

Comment: What's the reason for step 2? If you had an Open API definition you'd be all set for code gen wouldn't you? Is there a need for any transformation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it would be difficult to generate a documentation automatically if you don't have access to the source code. As you said in Option 1, your best bet is to probably write your own OpenAPI spec for this API.

If you end up manually creating your doc, I highly recommend to use Swagger Editor to write up and verify the doc: https://editor.swagger.io/